# Execute shortcodes in PHP

Tags: shortcode

I have a geolocation shortcode which i am adding in the post editor to display different information based on user's location, works perfectly by having it in the post page content.

How can i execute this shortcode [geolocation][/geolocation] inside a PHP file of my theme? i am using a free to modify Wordpress theme and i want to add a new `<span>[geolocation][/geolocation]Information text content</span>` but inside the theme's .php file, how can i do that? if i add straight the `<span>[geolocation][/geolocation]Information text content</span>` it will show the shortcode as text, it won't execute, please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[your shortcode goes here]' ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can Execute the shortcode in php like the following

```
echo do_shortcode("[geolocation]");
```